# How to create text content for one cell based on other cells's content in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

First of all I want to say that I've searched for this on SO and I found a few questions similar to mine, but they deal more with numbers and not text.

The other thing is that I'm not sure if what I want to do requires formulas or VBA, so I think that asking about it will help me understand that.

What I need to do is the following: I have an excel spreadsheet where each row (product) has many columns that contain text (specifications). I need to add a new column that will be the description of the product, which should have some pre-made text and some text that comes from the other columns.

Example of one of those descriptions:

```
This item has a weight of (value of cell B12) and can be found in the following colors: (value of cell D12). It can be used for (value of cell E12) and has a price of (value of cell F12)
```

What is the best approach to achieve something like that? Formulas? VBA? If possible any specific example would be great too!

Comment: formula with string concatenation: `="This item ..." & B12 & " and can ..."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be exactly what you're looking for:

```
=CONCATENATE("This item has a weight of ", B12, "and can be found in the following colors", D12,". It can be used for ", E12, "and has a price of ", F12)
```

You're just using the concatenate function to add the values of those cells into a string.  Any part of the string should be in quotes, and whenever you want to include another cell, just close your current quote, add a comma, a space, and then another comma.  You can then close the concatenation with a bracket or start another string.

Comment: Is there a benefit of using Concatenate instead of just putting everything together with quotes and & ?  (i.e. ="This is the " & b1 & " and then this..." & C1) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also, in addition to Concatenate, use just quotes and commas.

You can enter this to the address bar:

```
="This item has a weight of " & B12 & " and can be found in the following colors" & D12 ". It can be used for " & E12
```

...etc.  Just put your non-changing text in quotes, separate by "&" and put the cell reference. Also keep in mind you can use anchors, if you want to drag that formula up/down (anchors are the $ in the cell reference, i.e. $B$12).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [concatenate function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/CONCATENATE-function-870e82a1-d47d-440e-9a77-23e7639eda1d) to achieve this: 
 
[image]

 
you can put this formula in **G2** and copy and drag down.

```
=CONCATENATE("This item has a weight of ", B2, " and can be found in the following colors ", D2,". It can be used for ",E2, " and has a price of  ", F2,".")
```

there you go.